# React signals wont render async data

Tags: reactjs, preact-signal

In the React component below, I want to fetch data from the server and then present it in component html, the data is arriving and i can see in the console.lo, but the component wont be rendering it.

1. Why the data is not shown in the html even though `console.log` shows the data?
2. Is this the case for `signal`? `createSignal`? `useSignal`?

```
export const ManagementUsersList = () => {
  const list = signal([]);

  effect(() => {
    client()
      .get('/user')
      .then(({ data }) => {
        console.log(data);
        list.value = data;
      });
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {JSON.stringify(list.value)}
    </div>
  );
};
```